# QTimer's connection to timeout-method does not work in TestCases (Python)

Tags: python, qt, timer, pyqt, testcase

I just finished a software and want to test it now with help of python's `TestCase`. The method `test_show_video` should start a `QTimer`. It is connected to `test_run_iteration`, which sums up an index up by one every 0,1 seconds. Before `assert` is called, the method has three seconds time to sum up the index, so it should be bigger then zero. But it is not. Does anybody have a clue? In fact, the timeout-connection to the timer seems to be wrong.

```
try:
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
except RuntimeError:
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()

class TestProgressPresenter(TestCase):

    def test_show_video(self):

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.test_run_iteration)
        self.timer.start(100)
        self.index = 0

        millis = start_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

        while start_time + 3000 > millis:
            millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

        assert self.index > 0

    def test_run_iteration(self):
        self.index += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are blocking the Qt event loop during the `while` loop for 3 seconds. Actually the timer's `timeout` signal is not called until control returns to the event loop and that's when the while is completed and `test_show_video` is finished.

If you want the timer to get triggered you should make sure that the events are processed during the while loop checks. For that you can have some thing like :

```
while start_time + 3000 > millis:
    millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    QApplication.processEvents(QEventLoop.AllEvents)
```

It can be even easier to wait for some seconds using a local event loop :

```
self.loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
QTimer.singleShot(3000, loop.quit)
loop.exec()

assert self.index > 0
```